# how to sort rows in r dataframe in descending order

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
 no    no1    no2    no3    no4
 A       0     34     54     21
 B      43      0     23     65
 C      56     23      0      0
```

I want to print all non zero values of column names in descending order (top 3). Desired dataframe would be

```
 no    no1    no2    no3     no4          names
 A       0     34     54      21    no3 no2 no1
 B      43      0     23      65    no4 no1 no3
 C      56     23      0       0        no1 no2
```

I am using following function in R to print the array in names columns. What I can not do is sorting it in descending order.

```
     simplify2array(apply(df[2:5],1,function(x) paste(names(df[2:5])[x!=0],collapse="")))
```

how can I modify above function to accomodate sorting rows in descending order and taking only top 3 values

Comment: I think your first element in `names` would be `no3 no2 no4` as `no1` is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to loop through the rows, `sort` the non-zero elements in descending, with `head`, we can subset the first 'n' elements (based on the OP's comments), get the `names` and then `paste` it together

```
df1$names <- apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) 
             paste(names(head(sort(x[x!=0], decreasing = TRUE), 3)), collapse=" "))
df1
#  no no1 no2 no3 no4       names
#1  A   0  34  54  21 no3 no2 no4
#2  B  43   0  23  65 no4 no1 no3
#3  C  56  23   0   0     no1 no2
```

Comment: I want only top 3 values of column names to be printed. In above code all the values are getting printed

Comment: @Neil In that case wrap it with `head`, updated the code or `sort(x[x!=0], decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]`